# Did Adi Shankaracharya really try to make people'Bhagavad-vimukhi' as claimed the Gaudiya Vaishnavas?

Tags: vedanta, adi-shankaracharya, gaudiya-vaishnavism

**According to the sloka of Padma-Purana quoted in Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita, Sri Adi Sankaracharya deluded people by preaching a false doctrine and made them away (vimukha) from God :**

According to Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita, Sri Chaitanyadeva quoted the slokas of Padma-Purana (CC 2/6/162-164)

"Sri Krishna's order to Shiva : " Swaagamaih kalpitastawamcha janaan madbimukhaan kuru" -- make peole distarcted from me by creating your own imaginary paths."

"Shiva's statement in Padma-Purana to Devi : Mayavaadam asat shaastram prachchannam baudhdham uchchyate/ Maya eva bihitam devi kalau brahmana-murtina// -- Mayavaad is a false doctrine which is buddhism in disguise. I have preached this in Kaliyuga taking a brahmin form."

**Is there any validity of the claim as evident from the commentaries written by Sri Adi Sankara or is the claim a consrtucted one?**

Comment: Answers to this question may be opinion based. It depends on which part of the commentaries are quoted and how they are interpreted.

Comment: @Lazy Lubber Let us see whether any evidence is there that suggests that Sankara was against worshipping God by individuals  referrend to as "janaan"

Comment: What constitutes "bhagavad vimukha" is subjective. PS: I am not saying the question is bad or needs to be closed.

Comment: This is opinion based as Adavitins believe these verses in Padma Purana uttara Khanda are later day additions. More importantly, as opponents say Adi Shankara's philosophy is not Mayavada but Brahmavada. Mayavada considers Maya to be superior to Brahman but not in case of Shankra Adavita. Opponents of Advaita have different opinions on Advaita.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think the slokas are interppolatios to any sensible person. But where did Sankara insult Iswara as they claim?

Comment: @Partha [this site](http://www.advaita-vedanta.in/dispelling-doubts) clears all accusations on Adi Shankara.

Comment: @TheDestroyer thnx so much

Comment: I personally don't believe in any such Puranic verses regarding Adi Shankara. If you see Kurma Purana, it says Adi Shankara will revive Sanatana Dharma so basically I personally think these are later day additions. Even Madhvacharya is attacked in the Saura Purana.

Comment: @Surya Kanta Bose Chowdhury i think Mahaprabhu also never quoted this sloka.its interpolation